# How to add border radius around the table using iText7 (8.0.0)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext, itext7

I'm struggling for a while now to introduce border radius around the table but nothing seems to work. Is it possible that border radius is not supported?

I tried with this block of code but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
    private static Cell CreateGeneralInformationCell()
    {
        var generalInformation = new Cell().SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);

      
        var outerTable = new Table(1)
            .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
            .SetBorder(new SolidBorder(new DeviceGray(0), 1f))
            .SetBorderRadius(new BorderRadius(5f))
            .SetMarginTop(5f);

        
        var innerTable = new Table(1)
            .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
            .SetPadding(5f);

        var companyInfo = new Paragraph("test")
            .SetBold()
            .SetFontSize(12);

        var addressInfo = new Paragraph("test")
            .SetFontSize(10);

        innerTable.AddCell(new Cell().Add(companyInfo).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
        innerTable.AddCell(new Cell().Add(addressInfo).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));

        
        outerTable.AddCell(new Cell().Add(innerTable).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));

        
        generalInformation.Add(outerTable);

        return generalInformation;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.